# find filenames NOT ending in specific extensions on Unix?

Tags: command-line, find

Is there a simple way to recursively find all files in a directory hierarchy, that do *not* end in a list of extensions? E.g. all files that are not *.dll or *.exe

UNIX/GNU find, powerful as it is, doesn't seem to have an `exclude` mode (or I'm missing it), and I've always found it hard to use regular expressions to find things that *don't* match a particular expression.

I'm in a Windows environment (using the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) port of most GNU tools), so I'm equally open for Windows-only solutions.

Comment: This question has more answers here: [List files not matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525437/11725753)

Answer (score 443, accepted):

Or without `(` and the need to escape it:

```
find . -not -name "*.exe" -not -name "*.dll"
```

and to also exclude the listing of directories

```
find . -not -name "*.exe" -not -name "*.dll" -not -type d
```

or in positive logic ;-)

```
find . -not -name "*.exe" -not -name "*.dll" -type f
```

Comment: `-not` can be replaced by `'!'` (Quote is recommended). On the other hand, `-name` is case sensitive while `-iname` is case insensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure how long I spun my wheels figuring out that `!` unquoted causes inconsistent problems depending on how your command is invoked.

I would not recommend subbing `"!"` for `-not` It's only one character less, one keystroke more, and invites misuse.

Answer (score 53):

```
find . ! \( -name "*.exe" -o -name "*.dll" \)
```

Comment: On Solaris `-not` is a bad option, this one with `!` works nice :)

Answer (score 12):

```
$ find . -name \*.exe -o -name \*.dll -o -print
```

The first two -name options have no -print option, so they skipped. Everything else is printed.

Answer (score 8):

You could do something using the grep command:

```
find . | grep -v '(dll|exe)$'
```

The `-v` flag on `grep` specifically means "find things that **don't** match this expression."

Comment: grep -v '\.(dll|exe)$'     would prevent matching againsta a file or dir named "dexe" for example

Comment: This only works with extended regexp. I had to add -E (or use egrep) to make this work.

Comment: You could use two expressions instead of `-E`: `grep -v -e '\.dll$' -e '\.exe$'`

Answer (score 3):

Linux/OS X:

Starting from the current directory, recursively find all files ending in .dll or .exe

```
find . -type f | grep -P "\.dll$|\.exe$"
```

Starting from the current directory, recursively find all files that DON'T end in .dll or .exe

```
find . -type f | grep -vP "\.dll$|\.exe$"
```

Notes:

(1) The P option in grep indicates that we are using the Perl style to write our regular expressions to be used in conjunction with the **grep** command. For the purpose of excecuting the **grep** command in conjunction with regular expressions, I find that the Perl style is the most powerful style around.

(2) The v option in grep instructs the shell to exclude any file that satisfies the regular expression

(3) The $ character at the end of say ".dll$" is a delimiter control character that tells the shell that the filename string ends with ".dll"

Answer (score 3):

```
find  /data1/batch/source/export   -type f -not  -name "*.dll" -not -name "*.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

one more :-)

```
$ ls -ltr
total 10
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb         47 Dec 23 14:46 test1
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:40 test4
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:40 test3
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:40 test2
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:41 file5
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:41 file4
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:41 file3
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:41 file2
-rw-r--r--    1 scripter     linuxdumb          0 Jan  4 23:41 file1
$ find . -type f ! -name "*1" ! -name "*2" -print
./test3
./test4
./file3
./file4
./file5
$
```

[Unix find command reference](http://www.scripterworld.com/2009/07/unix-find-command-with-examples-and.html)

Comment: Quote that ! or you're gonna have problems once you put this into a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Use -not along with -regex

```
find . -type f -not -regex '.*\.\(exe\|dll\)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions on this page aren't desirable if you have a long list of extensions -- maintaining a long sequence of `-not -name 'this' -not -name 'that' -not -name 'other'` would be tedious and error-prone -- or if the search is programmatic and the list of extensions is built at runtime.

For those situations, a solution that more clearly separates data (the list of extensions) and code (the parameters to `find`) may be desirable.  Given a directory & file structure that looks like this:

```
.
└── a
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 15.xml
    ├── 8.dll
    ├── b
    │   ├── 16.xml
    │   ├── 2.txt
    │   ├── 9.dll
    │   └── c
    │       ├── 10.dll
    │       ├── 17.xml
    │       └── 3.txt
    ├── d
    │   ├── 11.dll
    │   ├── 18.xml
    │   ├── 4.txt
    │   └── e
    │       ├── 12.dll
    │       ├── 19.xml
    │       └── 5.txt
    └── f
        ├── 13.dll
        ├── 20.xml
        ├── 6.txt
        └── g
            ├── 14.dll
            ├── 21.xml
            └── 7.txt
```

You can do something like this:

```
## data section, list undesired extensions here
declare -a _BADEXT=(xml dll)

## code section, this never changes
BADEXT="$( IFS="|" ; echo "${_BADEXT[*]}" | sed 's/|/\\|/g' )"
find . -type f ! -regex ".*\.\($BADEXT\)"
```

Which results in:

```
./a/1.txt
./a/b/2.txt
./a/b/c/3.txt
./a/d/4.txt
./a/d/e/5.txt
./a/f/6.txt
./a/f/g/7.txt
```

You can change the extensions list without changing the code block.

**NOTE** doesn't work with native OSX `find` - use gnu find instead.