# How to send list of file in a folder to a txt file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I'm fairly new to Linux (CentOS in this case).  I have a folder with about 2000 files in it.  I'd like to ideally execute a command at the command prompt that would write out the name of all the files into a single txt file.

If I have to, I could write an actual program to do it too, I was just thinking there might be a way to simply do it from the command prompt.

Comment: Be careful with this, it's possible for filenames to contain all sorts of tricky characters. eg. newline

Answer (score 117, accepted):

you can just use

```
ls > filenames.txt
```

(usually, start a shell by using "Terminal", or "shell", or "Bash".)  You may need to use `cd` to go to that folder first, or you can `ls ~/docs > filenames.txt`

Comment: Thankfully I googled this before writing a little bash script!

Comment: For absolute path `printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* >filenames.txt`

Comment: For anything beyond this trivial use, you should probably avoid `ls`.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: What if I want to save the each filename in a double quote " " and each such "" separated by a comma? Please tell how to do that. 
i.e if file names are a,b,c,d,e; I want them to be saved to a text file as `"a","b","c","d","e"`

Comment: Just to add to this answer: " ls > filenames.txt " creates/overwrites the content of the txt file. If you want to append more filenames/data (without overwriting previous entries) in an existing txt file simply use double  >>, i.e. ls >> filenames.txt  :)

Answer (score 11):

If only names of regular files immediately contained within a directory (assume it's `~/dirs`) are needed, you can do

```
find ~/docs -type f -maxdepth 1 > filenames.txt
```

Comment: How to ignore certain files like backup files (files having "~" as suffix in their names) ?

Comment: @VickyDev One way would be to filter `find`'s output through `grep`: `find ~/docs -type f -maxdepth 1 | grep -v '~$' > filenames.txt`

Comment: @VickyDev A cleaner way is to use `find`'s `-name` with `-not`: `find ~/docs -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -name '*~' > filenames.txt`

Comment: @VickyDev Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341467/unix-find-for-finding-file-names-not-ending-in-specific-extensions for more on the topic