# YOLO (Darknet): How to detect a whole directory of images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darknet

The Darknet guide to detect objects in images using pre-trained weights is here: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

The command to run is:

`./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg`

The last argument is the path to a file, I've tried to change it to `data/*.jpg` but didn't work.

**How to use Darknet to detect a whole directory of images?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the link mentioned below, one can use cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet module to read darknet, trained weights and configuration file to make a loaded model in python. Once the model is loaded, one can simply use for loop for prediction.
[Please refer this link for further clarification](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/)

Comment: How would you use a loop for prediction?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to detect objects on a list of images based on this repository [AlexeyAB/darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet).

```
./darknet detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights < images_files.txt
```

You can generate the file list either from the command line ([Send folder files to txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112151/how-to-send-list-of-file-in-a-folder-to-a-txt-file-in-linux) ) or using a GUI tool like Nautilus on Ubuntu.

Two extra flags `-dont_show -save_labels` will disable the user interaction, and save the detection results to text files instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick to make Darknet executable load weights once and infer multiple image files. Use `expect` to do the trick.

Install `expect`:

```
sudo yum install expect -y
#sudo apt install expect -y
```

Do object detection on multiple images:

```
expect <<"HEREDOC"
  puts "Spawning...";
  spawn ./darknet detect cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg yolov3-tiny.weights;
  set I 0;

  expect {
    "Enter Image Path" {
      set timeout -1;

      if {$I == 0} {
        send "data/dog.jpg\r";
        incr I;
      } elseif {$I == 1} {
        send "data/kite.jpg\r";
        incr I;
      } else {
        exit;
      }

      exp_continue;
    }
  }
HEREDOC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is loading Darknet from Python2 (not 3, Darknet is using Python2).

1a) Clone darknet as described in https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

1b) Go to the cloned dir, download `yolov3-tiny.weights` and `yolov3.weights` as said in https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

2) Copy `darknet/examples/detector.py` to `darknet` dir

3) Edit the new detector.py

- Change .load_net line to use: `cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg` and `yolov3-tiny.weights`
- Change .load_meta line to use: `cfg/coco.data`

4a) Detect objects in images by adding some `dn.dectect` lines in detector.py

4b) Run detector.py