# List files not matching a pattern?

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob, ls

Here's how one might list all files matching a pattern in bash:

```
ls *.jar
```

How to list the complement of a pattern? i.e. all files not matching *.jar?

Comment: this probably shouldn't be labeled regex,  * is a shell-globbing wildcard, and is not a regular expression *, which is the "zero or more quantifier".

Comment: Good point, although I'm learning that using regex is probably better practice for getting the matches you expect.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
ls | grep -v '\.jar$'
```

for instance.

Comment: How can you do two filetypes?

Comment: @Silver89, `ls | grep -v -e '\.one$' -e '\.two$'` for instance.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), thank you.

Comment: It would be a bit more efficient to use     ls --ignore='\.jar' to prevent having to call another program.

Comment: @xizdaqrian, good point, didn't know about that. But it's gnu-only, I believe.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I would say unless you use `ls -1`

Comment: `ls -1` doesn't do much good, I think it actually happens automatically if output is not a terminal. Problem is that "considered harmful" articles considered harmful :) One has to be aware of all implications when one parses `ls` output, but if one knows what one's doing one can do whatever one wants :)

Answer (score 95):

Use egrep-style extended pattern matching.

```
ls !(*.jar)
```

This is available starting with bash-2.02-alpha1.
Must first be enabled with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

As of bash-4.1-alpha there is a config option to enable this by default.

Comment: Yay for mentioning the shopt -s extglob!

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The answer marked as correct doesn't use the shell directly, it uses an ancillary command.

Comment: @dbw - Even if I like more this answer, the accepted answer is ok for the question. The OP does not specifically ask for using "the shell directly".

Comment: "egrep-style" is quite misleading, as grep deals with regular expressions, while this here are shell patterns.

Comment: It did not work for me. For long lists returning about 2000 items, I got "argument list to long". I guess it happens because the branches expand the outputs of the  command inside them. So it becomes an argument list with about 2000 items which is really long.

Comment: For some reason I cannot use it with `watch` if I enclose the command in single or double quotes. I get unexpected token.

Answer (score 42):

Little known bash expansion rule:

```
ls !(*.jar)
```

Comment: bash: !: event not found. What do I need?

Comment: Try executing 'shopt -s extglob' on the command line first, then typing the command.

Answer (score 25):

With an appropriate version of `find`, you could do something like this, but it's a little overkill:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.jar'
```

`find` finds files. The `.` argument specifies you want to start searching from `.`, i.e. the current directory. `-maxdepth 1` tells it you only want to search one level deep, i.e. the current directory. `! -name '*.jar'` looks for all files that *don't* match the regex `*.jar`.

Like I said, it's a little overkill for this application, but if you remove the `-maxdepth 1`, you can then recursively search for all non-jar files or what have you easily.

Comment: I do like this one because it works in zsh too, where some of the bash-extension ones do not (at least not with my zsh skill level :D )

Answer (score 18):

POSIX defines non-matching bracket expressions, so we can let the shell expand the file names for us.

```
ls *[!j][!a][!r]
```

This has some quirks though, but at least it is compatible with about any unix shell.

Comment: +1 for POSIX compliance. A little bash/python/ruby function combined with alias,i.e. "lsnot" could make it easily workable.

Comment: This doesn't match things shorter than three characters.

Answer (score 6):

If your `ls` supports it (`man ls`) use the `--hide=<PATTERN>` option. In your case:

```
$> ls --hide=*.jar
```

No need to parse the output of `ls` (because it's very bad) and it scales to not showing multiple types of files. At some point I needed to see what non-source, non-object, non-libtool generated files were in a (cluttered) directory:

```
$> ls src --hide=*.{lo,c,h,o}
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach can be using `ls -I` flag (Ignore-pattern).

```
ls -I '*.jar'
```

Comment: This is so simple and works for mine, many of the others didn't want to work.

Answer (score 4):

And if you want to exclude more than one file extension, separate them with a pipe `|`, like `ls test/!(*.jar|*.bar)`. Let's try it:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/1.jar test/1.bar test/1.foo
$ ls test/!(*.jar|*.bar)
test/1.foo
```

Looking at the other answers you might need to `shopt -s extglob` first.

Comment: You could shorten this to `!(*.[bj]ar)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be `ls -1|grep -v '\.jar$'`

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), thank you.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf don't be religious about rules such as parsing `ls` or using `goto`. Sometimes those solutions work best.

Comment: This isn’t one of those cases; `find . -print0 | grep -z '\.jar$'` works better even if you don’t want to use `--ignore` or Bash’s extended globbing.

That said, most people don’t want to read a whole article to understand a rule or what they *should* do, and you can fit a simple explanation and recommendation like “it doesn’t work in edge cases; use `find -print0` and `grep -z` instead” in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Some mentioned variants of this form:

```
ls -d *.[!j][!a][!r]
```

But this seems to be only working on bash, while this seems to work on both bash and zsh:

```
ls -d *.[^j][^a][^r]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -I "*.jar"
```

> -I, --ignore=PATTERN
> do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN

- It works without having to execute anything before
- It works also inside watch quotes: `watch -d 'ls -I "*.gz"'`, unlike `watch 'ls !(*.jar)'` which produces: `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

> Note: For some reason in Centos requires quoting the pattern after `-I` while Ubuntu does not