# linux search file based on file name pattern

Tags: linux, unix

I want to search a series of files based on the files name.

Here is my directory :

[image]

For example I had the file on above.

I only want to search out the file which is without _bak.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Which APIs?

Comment: Your question is far too vague to give a good answer. Are you trying to search the contents of the files? The filenames themselves? Are you just trying to get filenames that don't end in `_bak`?

Comment: Also, you should really post your directory contents in plain text, not an image. See the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: I'm not certain what the confusion is about.   The OP has tagged  this as `linux` `unix` and he's asking to pick out the files that don't have `_bak` at the end.  Am I missing something? (Although the formatting thing is true.  You should really use plain text.)

Comment: question seems very clear to me. pattern is starts with "ei469390ONL00", looks like windows, not linux, so dir

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [List files not matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525437/11725753)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you're wanting to limit your search to the current directory, use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name '*_bak'
```

If you want to recursively find in all directories remove the `-maxdepth 1`.

---

<sup>Edit in response to OP's comment</sup>

To get files that begin with `ei` and do not end with `_bak` use:

```
find . -type f -name 'ei*' -a ! -name '*_bak'
```

Comment: Hi Tim Pote , your answer is fine if without -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @user1154655 Changed per your suggestion.

Comment: Note, you must use quotes or double quotes. This won't work: `find . -name *_bak` because the shell will replace the `*_bak` with matching filenames in the current directory, hence the `unknown primary or operator` error you typically get. Use quotes or double quotes as in the answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this:

```
 find . -type f ! -iname "*_bak"
```

The above command will find all files that have not end with `_bak`.

Comment: The command is helpful. thanks . if the directory contain other files as well , but i just want to search out the file name starts with ei but without bak ?

Comment: This will do `find . -name 'ei*' -type f ! -iname "*_bak"`

Answer (score -2):

Use the Grep Invert Match option.

For example, if you want all the file without the word _bak, use :

```
grep -v *_bak /path/to/file
```

Comment: Hi Erwald, your answer doesn't work but thanks for your help as well.

Comment: `grep` would work if you pipe the output of `ls` to it. e.g. `ls . | grep -v _bak`