# List all files that do not match pattern using ls

Tags: shell, command-line, sed, terminal, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu)

I've read the `man` page for `ls`, and I can't find the option to list all that do **not** match the file selector. Do you know how to perform this operation?

For example:
lets say my directory is this:

```
> ls
a.txt b.mkv c.txt d.mp3 e.flv
```

Now I would like to do something that does the following

```
> ls -[SOME_OPTION] *.txt
b.mkv d.mp3 e.flv
```

Is there such an option?

If not, is there a way to pipe the output of `ls` to another function (possibly `sed`) that shows only the ones that I would like?

I don't know exactly how to do this, but I'm imagining it would be something like:

```
> ls | sed [SOMETHING]
```

I really should learn how to use `sed`,`awk`,and `grep`, but I keep getting stuck at understanding how to write the regexes. I understand the concept of regular expressions clearly, but I get confused between regexes that use different syntax.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I am running Mac OS X, so the functions may be slightly different from the ones discussed in other answers for the unix/linux shell (hence some of my confusion with `sed`,`awk`,and `grep`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525437/608639

Answer (score 59, accepted):

this may be help you

```
ls --ignore=*.txt
```

It will not display the .txt files in your directory.

Comment: This one worked well for me. You can string --ignore switches together, and thus ignore e.g. all txt files, all files starting with a j and all files with a name containing 'bar': `ls --ignore=*.txt --ignore=j* --ignore=*bar*`

Comment: I get illegal option when I use that on El Capitan
ls --ignore=*pdf
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

Comment: Thanks. Actually this should be the accepted answer!!

Answer (score 18):

maybe this command will help you

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 ! -path "*txt"
```

Comment: This works nicely with many different selectors as the `path` parameter. Thank you! One thing I found was that I could do `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path "*txt"` too.

Now what would I have to use if I had a Regex for filtering the list?

Comment: if you want use Regex , use grep . ex . you have 3 files like "a b c" , use ls | grep -v "[a|b]" , then it will display c .and then if you have 3 files a aa aaa , use "ls | grep -v "a+" , then it will only display "a".

Comment: ./ Argument is optional since find command already start searching down from current Directory tree

Comment: Mani R's asnwer is the valid answer for the original question.

Answer (score 15):

```
ls|grep -v ".txt"
```

does this helps?

Comment: This works for the case I gave you, but really I'm looking for something that works with any selectors. For example, If I wanted to not show the ones that had the `x` character followed by the word `in`, I need to use the `*x*in*` selector. This wouldn't be possible using your example I think.

Comment: @KaushikShankar I think it will work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 8):

*ls* just lists what arguments it is presented with. `*.txt` gets expanded to `a.txt c.txt` before *ls* sees it, try `echo *.txt`.

To do what you ask with *sed* you can delete the pattern from its input, for example:

```
ls | sed '/\.txt$/d'
```

Would delete all lines ending with `.txt`.

With *bash* and *zsh* you can have the shell do the inverted expansion, with bash it would be:

```
ls !(*.txt)
```

zsh:

```
ls *~*.txt
```

Note that both shells need the extended glob option to be enabled, `shopt -s extglob` with *bash* and `setopt extendedglob` with *zsh*.

Comment: Thanks for showing me another zsh feature! It's awesome.

Answer (score 5):

One way using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Unfortunately, I think there may be an issue with running on Mac OS X.

The error I get is the following:
Command:
`>find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n"`
Error:
`39m\n"find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: @KaushikShankar: Yes ignore the printf statement, it will only neaten your ouput to provide a list of files similar to how `ls` would work. It seems `BSD find` doesn't understand it.