# Hiding all directories that begin with a capitalized letter using `ls` in zsh

Tags: regex, unix, zsh

I'm trying to use `ls` in zsh (running on macOS) to show all files and directories except directories that begin with a capital letter.

For example, my directory contains

> Archive/ data/ README.md test.txt

and I would like to run an `ls` command that returns only

> data/ README.md test.txt

I can use `ls -d [A-Z]*/` (note the terminating backslash to indicate directories) to show the directories I want to hide (e.g. only returns `Archive/`),

and referencing this [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634013/list-all-files-that-do-not-match-pattern-using-ls#answer-12635586) on using the inverted expansion in zsh with the `ls *~` syntax,

I tried (what I think is) the negation of the above using `ls -d *~[A-Z]*/` but this doesn't work (it hides nothing).

Moreover, using `ls -d *~[A-Z]*` (without the terminating backslash) returns `data/ test.txt` but this is not my desired result since I also want to show the file `README.md` which begins with a capital letter.

Note that I have enabled the extended glob option in zsh, using `setopt extendedglob`.

Any help on the correct regex/glob syntax for `ls` in zsh to obtain my desired output would be very much appreciated. Thank you! :)

**Edit:** There are two very useful answers that work, but any concise answers using `ls` in zsh (using the extended glob option) would still be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

My version of `ls` does not directly support regular expressions, I think you are depending upon shell globbing.  Perhaps try piping to grep.  Something like:

```
 ls  | grep -v  '^[A-Z].*'
```

Notice that the regular expression is in quotes.  The `^` specifies the beginning of the string.  The switch `-v` is the negation of the match.

Sorry, now I understand your requirements better.  You could string the `find` command to do this.  Try the following:

```
find -E . -regex "\./[^A-Z].*" -type d -exec echo Directory: {} ';' -exec find {} -type f -maxdepth 1 \;
```

I tested this on a Mac with the following hierarchy:

```
find .
.
./Test
./Test/Plain File
./aatest
./aatest/BigTest
./aatest/BigTest/Big File
./aatest/BigTest/small File
./aatest/bb File
./aatest/aaFile
```

And got the following output:

```
Directory: ./aatest
./aatest/bb File
./aatest/aaFile
Directory: ./aatest/BigTest
./aatest/BigTest/Big File
./aatest/BigTest/small File
```

Please note that I added the text "Directory" to the echo command to differentiate the two types of output.

Comment: Thanks @Bill! This is useful. However, it still has the problem of also hiding capitalized _files_, not only capitalized directories.

Comment: Appreciate your update @Bill. This now works! I can then just pipe to `ls` for desired results. Ideally I was hoping for a syntactically simple function using `ls` like in my attempted code in the question, but this will do the trick for an alias. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit verbose, but you might use `ls -l` and prevent the `total` using `grep -v "^total"` and then pipe the output to awk.

In awk, print the last field followed by `/` if the first field starts with `d` and the last field does not start with an uppercase char A-Z

Or print the last field if the the first field does not start with `d`

```
ls -l | grep -v "^total" | awk '{
  if ($1 ~ /^d/ && $NF ~ /^[^A-Z]/){
    print $NF"/"
  } else if ($1 ~ /^[^d]/){
    print $NF
  }
}'
```

In a single line:

```
 ls -l | grep -v "^total" | awk '{if($1~/^d/ && $NF~/^[^A-Z]/){print $NF"/"} else if($1~/^[^d]/){print $NF}}'
```