# Hadoop hdfs shell command for inverse pattern search

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I would like to know if we can list files in an HDFS directory with files NOT matching the given pattern.

For instance, assume I have some files with names containing some date values [eg: 'file201606250001.csv'].

If I need to get list of files not belonging to a date pattern, say '*20160629*', what command can I use?

I tried to give the following command, but it still is listing all files (including the ones matching the pattern I wanted to exclude).

```
hdfs dfs -ls /test/* | grep -v '*20160629*'
```

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525459/3824296), but still it returns all files.

Comment: Pipe the results of an `-ls` through `grep`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files not matching a pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525437/list-files-not-matching-a-pattern)

Comment: @Inian I tried that solution, but it is not working in my case. It still lists files with the pattern to be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First list the file and then `grep` other than your pattern (`-v` option)

`hadoop fs -ls /dir/path/to/search |grep -v '20160629'`

Comment: That worked. I was giving `grep -v '*20160629*'` after the pipe as the command. Thanks!