# ls command for specific name convention

Tags: regex, grep, wildcard, ls

I am trying to use the `ls` command to list specific subdirectories within a directory.

The subdirectories have the following name convention:

```
abc.wiki.git
abc.git
cde.wiki.git
cde.git
fgh.wiki.git
fgh.git
```

I would only like to list the subdirectories that do not have "wiki" within the name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files not matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525437/list-files-not-matching-a-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see everything in said sub-folders you could use:

```
ls | grep -v wiki | xargs ls
```

If you don't want to see inside each subdirectory just use:

```
ls | grep -v wiki
```

Comment: Why `| xargs ls`?

Comment: @axiac I thought he wants to look inside each git folder without wiki in the name?

Comment: A good reason to pipe the result to `xargs ls` is to invoke `ls` with flags. The first `ls` lists only the file and directory names and the second `ls` can be invoked with `-a`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this use case, `find` is more clever.

`$ find . -type d -not -name "*wiki*"`