# linux cat files excluding the ones beginning with a certain prefix

Tags: linux, cat

I am trying to cat all png files in a directory and pipe them to the ffmpeg command:

```
cat *.png | ffmpeg
```

it works but I now wanto to exclude from the list all png file beginning with the prefix 'legend_'. How do I achieve this? I know that using ls I can type:

```
ls -I legend_* -I *.jpg
```

I found info about grep, ls , etc but there are confusing information regarding the command cat and none seem to work like using

```
!(legend_)
! -name legend_
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files not matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525437/608639), [List files not matching given string in filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/51981/56041), [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -name '*.png' ! -name 'legend_*' -exec cat {} \; | ffmpeg
```

With bash, using the `extglob` option, you can write:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(legend_*).png
```

Since the `extglob` option is not POSIX conform, meaning it is not guaranteed to work in a POSIX shell I would recommend to use `find`.