# move files that no not contain specific string

Tags: bash, find, mv

I would like to move files using `mv` that do not contain the letter `S` in the filename. Could not find anyhting in the mv manual. Maybe combination with `find` or `grep`? It has to be case-sensitive.

input:

```
  file1
  fileS1
  file2
  fileS2
```

file to move:

```
  file1
  file2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the selection in pure Bash without any extra software, if you enable **extended globbing**, which is off by default:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv !(*S*) /target/dir
```

For more information, search for `extglob` in the `bash(1)` manual page (the info is at the second match).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Ignore-pattern switch from `ls`, like:

```
mv $(ls -I '*S*') /target/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with the `-not` flag for example.

```sh
find /path/to/source/dir -type f -not -name '*S*' \
    | xargs mv -t /path/to/target/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

[GREP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/grep-command-in-unixlinux/)'s `-v` flag can also be used here. According to the docs,

> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Just use

```
ls | grep -v '*S*' | xargs mv -t target_dir/
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525437/list-files-not-matching-a-pattern) post.