# Meaning of Exclamation mark in Bash command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have found this command online, finding and displaying hardlinks to a file e.g. text.txt.

My question: What is the exclamation mark (!) doing in this command?

```
find $PWD ! -type d -links +1 -ls | sort -n|cut -d" " -f29 | grep --color=auto "$2"
```

Comment: It is also know as a *"Bang"*

Comment: Try using `man find` for documentation on the syntax of that command.

Comment: Have a look at, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341467/unix-find-for-finding-file-names-not-ending-in-specific-extensions (and the man page of `find`).

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

This negates the next condition. So `! -type d` means "not a directory".

There is one problem, though: `!` is also a special character which is used to make bash do history expansion. That's why you often have to escape (`... \! ...`) or quote it (`... "!" ...`).

See also: The manual for `find` (try `man find` or `info find`).

- https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html

Comment: I was just reading [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22Hello_World.21.22) and it seems like single quotes are actually needed... (esp before Bash 4.3) (\! might work...)